# How to get the numbers that multiplied with $N$ become integers?

Tags: number-theory

How can I get all the numbers (between $0$ and $1$) that multiplied with integer $N$ become integers.

Thanks!

Comment: Are said numbers supposed to be between $0$ and $1$, and if so, do you just mean all reals?

Comment: Is $N$ an integer?

Comment: Yes and yes, sorry if not clear.

Comment: OK, then the answer by @Marc is correct. Also, you might want to use the word "integer" instead of "whole number without decimals"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers 
$$
\frac{1}{N},\ldots,\frac{N-1}{N}
$$
are the ones you are looking for. Why? Choose $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $gcd(p,q) = 1$, $\frac{p}{q}<1$ and $N\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{N}$, then $q|N$. Therefore 
$$
\frac{p}{q} = \frac{p(N/q)}{q(N/q)} = \frac{p(N/q)}{N},
$$
where $p(N/q)< N$, because $p<q$, so $\frac{p}{q}N<N$.

Comment: Minor nit: Include the assumption $GCF(p,q)=1$, i.e. the fraction ${p}\over{q}$ is in reduced form to ensure $q | N$.

Comment: Good point, changed it. Thank you.